# Dismissing Anko Dialog in onClickListener

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I would like to dismiss Anko Dialog when pressing the button defined in my customLayout

```
val dialog = alert {
   val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.match_stats, null)
   val closeButton = view.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.closeButton)
   closeButton.setOnClickListener { _ -> dialog.dismiss()}
   customView = view
}
dialog.show()
```

I tried above code, unfortunately, I can’t get a reference to `dialog` in my `onClickListener`. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare variable before and assign `null`:

```
var dialog: DialogInterface? = null
dialog = alert {
   val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.match_stats, null)
   val closeButton = view.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.closeButton)
   closeButton.setOnClickListener { _ -> dialog?.dismiss()}
   customView = view
}.show()
```

Of course now your `dialog` variable is muttable and optional.

Comment: Ofc mutable and optional sucks, but I haven't found a better solution. Thanks!